# Mutation Observer addedNode Not available Instantly(delayed)

Tags: javascript, mutation-observers

I am using a mutation observer to watch for specific elements added to the DOM instead of using a setInterval with return when element is not found. Let me share my code:

Instead of this:

```js
var = myinterval = setInterval(function(){
if($('#my-div-id').length == 0) return;
$('#my-div-id').before('<div>I am an added div</div>');
});
```

I Use this:

```js
   var createMutationObserver = function(mutationObjectName, targetNodeName, dataFunction, mutationObjectType = 'id', targetNodeType = 'id'){

        if( $(mutationObjectType == 'id' ? '#' + mutationObjectName : '.' + mutationObjectName).length !== 0){
            dataFunction();
            return;
        }

        let targetNode = targetNodeType.toLowerCase() == 'id' ? document.getElementById(targetNodeName) : (targetNodeType.toLowerCase() == 'class' ? document.getElementsByClassName(targetNodeName)[0] : '' );

        let mutationObjectTypeClean = mutationObjectType.toLowerCase() == 'id' ? 'id' : (mutationObjectType.toLowerCase() == 'class' ? 'className' : '' );

        let currentMutation = new MutationObserver(function(mutationsList, observer) {
            // Use traditional 'for loops' for IE 11
            for(var mutation of mutationsList) {

                if (mutationType === 'childList' && mutation.type === 'childList') {
                    if(mutation.addedNodes.length !== 0){
                            if(mutation.addedNodes[0][mutationObjectTypeClean] == mutationObjectName){
                                // Code added here
                                dataFunction();
                                // Disconnect observer
                                observer.disconnect();
                                break;
                            }

                    }

                }


            }
        });

        currentMutation.observe(targetNode, { attributes: true, childList: true, subtree: false });
    };


createMutationObserver('documentBody' ,'my-div-id', () => {
$('#my-div-id').before('<div>I am an added div</div>');
console.log($('#my-div-id').length);
});
```

The "documentBody" id I used is the id of my body tag.

The issue I come across is that when I add the div with id "my-div-id" is that the mutation happens and the mutation observer works however the div with id "my-div-id" is not there and I get 0 when I console log and the before statement does not work.

Any ideas why the element is not there even if the mutation has fired?

Comment: Depending on how that div is added, it may be inside another element. The `addedNodes` array doesn't flatten all added nodes so you'll need to find the matching one yourself via querySelector and so on.

Comment: I understand what you mean and that is actually really helpful to refactor my code to catch nodes that might be nested thanks. However in my case the node is found as it's the only div added. The issue in my case is that even through I received the mutation from the observer the element doesn't seem to have already completely been added to the DOM.

Comment: The observer is always called after DOM was modified so the only explanation is that some other code modifies/removes this element. Anyway, without [MCVE](/help/mcve) that we can try ourselves this question is unlikely to get an answer.